# Rights management operation failed

Tags: exchange-server-2010

I have just set up a new exhange 2010 multitenant server with all roles installed.
When logging into the outlook web access and trying to create a email i get the error "Rights management operation failed."[screenshot showing error with additional details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt9v5.jpg)
I have tried disabling IRMenabled to false as can be seen in the next  screenshot and restarted IIS but still get the error
[screenshot showingIRMEnabled disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsqVH.jpg)

I have rebuilt ther exchange server twice but on both occassions got this error any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Rehan Miah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer had the original server that the error was on as i had given up waiting for a solution having posted my problem on forums.
 Today i tried rebuilding the server following all the exact same steps that i have documented. The only thing i can think of that was probably giving me the rights management operation failed error on the previous server was probably the date was most probably incorrect as i had read this on another forum.
 I had already tried disabling IRMEnabled previously but that did not resolve my problem at the time. So anybody else getting this error. if disablying IRMENABLED does not resolve **check to to ensure the date is correct on the server first**.

Answer (score 0):

Open the exchange management shell as administrator
and try this:

Set-OwaVirtualDirectory -Identity "Contoso\owa (default Web site)" -IRMEnabled $false

PS: Replace Contoso with your exchange server name!

Hope it helps u
good luck